# How to move a website without downloading and then uploading

Tags: web, website-hosting

Please forgive me if this has been asked but I could not find an answer.

**How can one move a website from one server to another without having to download the files (zipped or otherwise) and then uploading to the new server?**

I suspect this is possible via ftp, but am not sure how to do so.

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

In standard of FTP protocol is this function. But in my experience this is hard to configure for work and not any servers support this feature.

More simple is use SSH. If you have SSH access to any of this servers then you can login to shell on one server and transfer files from/to other server via FTP.

Comment: Many thanks for the reply. I am not sure of the SSH access, but will look into it and will get back to you within a few days.